# Get the minimum amount in a week

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a property_rate table and values like

```
id      start_date    end_date    rate
1       2017-11-19    2017-11-21  100
2       2017-11-22    2017-11-24  300
3       2017-11-25    2017-11-28  500
4       2017-11-29    2017-11-30  200
```

Here i want to get the row having lowest price in a week like

```
id     start_date     end_date    rate
1      2017-11-19     2017-11-21  100
```

What i have tried the below query but it is returning null

```
SELECT   MIN(rate_per_week) AS min_value FROM property_rate WHERE    start_date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: Your question is missing some information that'll allow us to help you. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: please mention your table name or tried code

Comment: Show attempt...

Comment: Please be so kind and provide more information about your table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved it by below query

SELECT MIN(rate_per_week) AS min_value FROM property_rate WHERE start_date >= '2017-21-11' group by week('2017-21-11')

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, start_date, end_date, rate FROM <Table> ORDER BY rate ASC LIMIT <amount of rows to show>;
```

Comment: What if there's a tie?

Answer (score 0):

You have to place your table name.
here is the working code

```
SELECT * FROM `table name` ORDER BY `rate` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: i dont want to get the value using limit, i want to get what the min amount in a particular week

Comment: first tell me one thing that how you are getting the week dates currenty?

Comment: @user3668438 He's ascending the results which means the lowest is at the top. Then he limits it by 1, so you always get the min amount.